# Samsung Internet not reading the flex-direction:column; property

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have built a website lately, and on a section Ive put:
a background image
an image above it
a h1 and
a h3.
Now, when I load my page on live server, everything looks fine. Same with opening it on chrome on my android, and so Safari, but when I open it on Samsung internet, the flex direction seems to be in row by default.
Heres my html code of that section:

```
      <section class="section-start img-cover" id="section--1">
        <img src="images/logo-no-background.png" class="" alt="gipsdesign">
        <div>
          <h1>UNTERNEHMEN, DAS SICH SPEZIALISIERT AUF:</h1>
          <h3>Energieeffiziente und umweltfreundliche Häuser für den heimischen Markt.</h3>
        </div>
      </section>
```

and heres my CSS code:

```
.section-start {
  background-image: url(../images/secition-1img.jpg);
  min-height: 600px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Ive tried to give the flex-direction:column to each element but that didnt seem to work.